# JavaFX updating item in a TableView

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I want to update the selectedItem in a TableView with a new one. 
This is the closest I've been able to come up with:

```
private ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private TableView tableview;

...
tableview.setItems(data);
... 

old = tableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
new = "New"
data.remove(old);
data.add(new);
```

If I do only the data.remove(old) (without adding after) the selectedItem dissapears from the TableView, if I only do the data.add(new) (without removing before) the new item is added. That's ok, but when I do the add after the remove (or vice versa) nothing happens.

Please shine some light on this.

Comment: What JavaFX version do you use? It reminds me of an old bug fixed in 2.2

Comment: I wonder whether making a change in one shot solves the issue? int index = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(); data.set(index, "New");

Comment: @SergeyGrinev I'm using javafx.runtime.version: 2.2.1-ea-b02.

Comment: @Lesiak: I've tried what you said but I'm having the same issue.

Comment: you may want to try old workaround: `data.remove(old); Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){ public void run() {data.add(newItem);};`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it updating the old item and doing a dirty trick to update the tableview.

```
old = new;

// dirty hack
tableview.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(false);
tableview.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(true);
```

is far from being an elegant solution, but it works for the moment.